# How to set the Xamarin.forms tab page unselected icon and text color in ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, tabbedpage

I have a xamarin forms application which have a tab page(shown in image).It will show in **android** devices is like this.
[image]

In **ios** it will look like this.
[image]

The problem as you can see the unselected icon and text in ios is bit duller than android counterpart. I actually set the color of selected and unselected icon and text in android by putting these lines in tab page xaml.

```
         android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#c4c0c0"
         android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#ffffff"
```

Now in ios I set the selected color by adding this line in AppDelegate.cs

```
 UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255);
```

But how can I adjust the color of unselected icon and text color in ios? Should I use any custom render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest 4.0 pre-release, there are two new properties working for both iOS and Android:

```
Color TabbedPage.UnselectedTabColorProperty { get; set; } //Bindable Property
Color TabbedPage.SelectedTabColorProperty { get; set; } //Bindable Property
```

Pull request here:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/4899

For older versions, you have to use a custom renderer. For example this is the code for getting white color when unselected:

```
TabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(255, 255, 255, 255);
```

Usually i use this code in the `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` override when doing other stuff like micromanaging tabbar height, background image, ecc...

```
    public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

        TabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(255, 255, 255, 255);

        //doing other customization stuff here

    }
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. I tried setting a global style on TabbedPage for iOS and that didn't work. I tried setting UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor in my AppDelegate's FinishedLaunching override and it didn't work. I simply cannot get the selected tab icon to change color from the default blue.

Comment: @MatthewBelk I had the same issue. I resolved it by adding `SelectedTabColor="White"` to my TabbedPage XAML.

Comment: @Monty - I tried that, too, I thought, but trying it again now and it works.